# Selecting specific columns in dataframe and append into new rows

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, jupyter-notebook

I've been figure out a way to rearrange the dataframe. My original dataframe looks like this:

```
df:

   YOB    Name   Treatment_1   Date_1       Treatment_2    Date_2
0  1974   John       A        2018-11-13         D         2018-12-13
1  1975   Jones      B        2018-11-14         E         2018-12-14
2  1976   Jack       C        2018-11-15         F         2018-12-15
```

Now I want my dataframe to show different Treatment information on  different row

```
df:
   YOB    Name   Treatment   Date      
0  1974   John       A      2018-11-13         
1  1974   John       D      2018-12-13
2  1975   Jones      B      2018-11-14         
3  1975   Jones      E      2018-12-14
4  1976   Jack       C      2018-11-15         
5  1976   Jack       F      2018-12-15
```

Can anyone help shed some light on this matter cause I've been stuck for days.

Thank you in advanced

Note: I've simplified it but the actual data-set will have more than 20 treatment related columns, is there a way to use ranges instead of typing every single column out? Sorry for not being clear in the beginning

Comment: What have you tried? You have many options. Consider the aptly named [`wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.wide_to_long.html).

Comment: `pd.wide_to_long(df,['Treatment','Date'],i=['YOB','Name'],j='drop',sep='_').reset_index(level=[0,1])
`

Comment: I've tried wide_to_long, it works but is there a more efficient way instead of typing each columns since there are more than 22 related column but with the same separator? Sorry for not being clear in the beginning :(

Comment: I don't think so, you'll have to use some sort of looping on columns and 'melting' each column individually then merging results, or you might have to write some regex logic go fetch the groups of columns together and build the parameter for pd.wide_to_long without typing the complete list.

Answer (score 1):

Use `pd.wide_to_long`:

```
df = df.rename(columns={'Data_2':'Date_2'})  #Fix typo error first.

pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Date','Treatment'], i=['YOB','Name'], j='No', sep='_', suffix='\d+')\
  .reset_index()
```

Output:

```
    YOB   Name  No        Date Treatment
0  1974   John   1  2018-11-13         A
1  1974   John   2  2018-12-13         D
2  1975  Jones   1  2018-11-14         B
3  1975  Jones   2  2018-12-14         E
4  1976   Jack   1  2018-11-15         C
5  1976   Jack   2  2018-12-15         F
```